# jQuery Grid and Google Maps Problem

Tags: google-maps, jqgrid

Have you ever used jQuery Grid with google maps?, it seems like jQuery grid bug google map, if i clic the map the litle hand will stay closed and drag the map in the way i move the mouse no mather if i m not clicking anymore. Any idead how can i fix this behavior? . I know its jQuery grid, because if i remove the grid the map behavior normal again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never realize why this happen, i just redesign my interface , and didnt use jQuery Grid.
I found some info on the official jQueyGrid Web, that this is a known issue...